# PHP - Value from table column to array

Tags: php, date, phpmyadmin

So I have a stores dates as array in my table. Stores as mediumtext. They looks like this:

```
"2021-05-29","2021-05-31","2021-06-01","2021-02-06"
```

I want to add them to an array. I am trying to do something like this:

```
$dateArray = array($row["dates"]);
```

When `echo $row["dates"]` it gives me the correct value: `"2021-05-29","2021-05-31","2021-06-01","2021-02-06"`, but I need them in an array.

But when using `echo $dateArray;` it only returns: `Array`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to "explode" those as an array, since they have a unique delimiter, that being a comma:

```
$dates = $row["dates"];
$dateArrayStrings = explode(",", $dates);
```

From there you could work with each how you want to.

Comment: When doing `echo $dateArrayStrings;` it still just ways `Array`.

Comment: Try `print_r()` instead of `echo()`

Comment: Nice, it displays the dates now. But normally I could do: `if (in_array(date("Y-m-d"),$dateArrayStrings)) {` How should I do it now? If I want to check if todays date is in the array, using the same format?

Comment: @Camilla will require some additional code to turn the string'd date to a real date. Can you upvote/accept my answer tho, im new here and needing some rep. I will look into the conversion for you tho.